# Reference for lattices as algebraic structures

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, lattice-theory

I want to study lattices as  a structure related to ring theory. I am familiar with lattices as a beginner but I want to go further and know their connections to ring theory. Do you know a book which is self contained and doesn't have many unsolved examples?
I also want to  know if there are books or survey papers having   latest researches on lattices and  connections to ring theory.

Comment: If they are to be related to ring theory, then the crucial axiom to consider is the distributive law: $a \wedge (b \vee c) = (a \wedge b) \vee (a \wedge c)$ [where it is helpful to think of $\wedge$ as 'multiplication' and $\vee$ as 'addition']. Unlike ring theory, though, it follows from this distributive law and the other lattice axioms that also 'addition' distributes over 'multiplication'. You can get some distance with such analogies, but they shouldn't be pushed too far.

Comment: Todd Trimble this comment has potential to  be a good answer....

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify the wording of "related to ring theory". There are two possible understandings : 1) one can study lattices as something similar to associative (and commutative?) rings, thinking of the two operations as "addition" and "multiplication", or 2) one can study lattices that are meaningfully appear in ring theory (lattices of ideals in a ring, lattices of subvarieties in a variety of rings etc.) The comment of Todd Trimble is presumably about the first interpretation, while the immediate reaction of a typical ring theorist will be along the lines of the second interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

**General lattice theory**
by *George Grätzer*.
The book is well written and easy to read. I note here

part of the  *Preface and Acknowledgment*:
...That is why most of the first two chapters
of the former book are reproduced here..., thus giving the reader a *self-contained* book.

part of the  *Preface to the Second Edition*:
... In the first appendix: Retrospective, I briefly review developments from the
point of view of this book, specifically, the major results of the last 20 years
and solutions of the problems proposed in this book. *It is remarkable how many
difficult problems have been solved!*
I was lucky in getting an exceptional group of people to write the other
appendices... .

I hope this book and its appendices can help you.